# Vertically Align divs and text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

```
[jsfiddle.net/c8q17Lu4/][1]
```

Hello,

I'm having trouble with probably an easy fix. I need to vertically align the '#header-right-b-headers' orange divs within the blue '#header-right-b' div, and also vertically align the text in the orange divs.

I've tried the vertical-align and display as inline block rules, and some others, and don't understand why it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the line-height for the  equal to the height of the wrapping div.

Add

```
.header-right-b-headers-end h3, .header-right-b-headers h3{
line-height: 20px;
}
```

this to your CSS.

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8q17Lu4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your line height for those headers equal to the height your setting for the divs.

```
line-height:20px;
```

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c8q17Lu4/1/ ?